# mod_rewrite recurrent pattern for seo

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have the following link

http://xyz.com/path1/path2/page/par1/par1value/par2/par2value/par3/par3value .... undefined number of parameters

I would like this to be converted via mod_rewrite to something like that:

http://xyz.com/path1/path2/page.php?par1=par1value&par2=par2value&par3=par3value&par4=par4value ...

I made many tries but none fully succeed.
I end up with something like that - for 2 parameters (it does not do recurrence though)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)\/(.+)\/(.+)\/(.+)\/(.+)[^/]+$ $1.php?$2=$3&$4=$5 [L]
```

I am not satisfied with this solution, 
Please help me building conditions correctly

Thanks in advance
Norbert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did it like that:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/(.*?)$ $1.php?route=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L]
```

and

- I am parsing the "route" in my PHP scripts
- removing the "route" from GET array as a part of SEO class

  ```
  public static function router($router = "route") {
      if ($route = GetFromGet($router)) {
          $arr = preg_split('/\//', $route);
          if (sizeof($arr)) {
              unset($_GET[$router]);
              foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
                  if (($key % 2) == 1) {
                      $_GET[$arr[$key - 1]] = $value;
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

So, somwhere in the beginning of my common files I call:

```
SEO::router();
```

The above solves the issue, however I am still curious whether it is possible by mod_rewrite itself.